# ES6: Is there a reason why the `function` keyword is needed?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a reason why the `function` keyword is needed for regular javascript functions? What is the design consideration behind it by Ecma International?

For me, the brackets `{}` after the function indicate that it is a function, hence it would seem logical that it can be omitted. At least, we should have two ways of writing it to reduce boilerplate.

*Note*, that arrow functions are not the same as regular function declarations because they are not hoisted.

Inside of an Object, we can specify it without a `function` keyword.

```
const person = {
  name: "Taylor",
  sayHello() {
    return `Hello! My name is ${this.name}.`;
  }
};
```

Why can we not do it outside the scope of an Object?

Comment: It's simply the way it has been specified. I guess the people at the standards bodies wanted it specifically this way but I don't know the exact reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One reason for it would be that, if it was made such that we were able to have function declarations without the `function` keyword, the syntax would be ambiguous. First keep in mind that:

- Semicolons are optional (and some prefer to write without them)
- Newlines are permitted between the end of an argument list `)` and the start of a function block `{`
- Plain blocks are permitted - that is, syntax like:

  ```
  console.log('foo');
  {
      console.log('bar');
  }
  ```

Then, if the following was permitted:

```
sayHello()
{
    console.log('baz');
}
```

What would it mean? Does it mean that this would be the definition of a `sayHello` function, or does it mean to invoke a function named `sayHello` and then start a new block?

Requiring function declarations to use the `function` keyword keeps things absolutely unambiguous.

Comment: Great answer, is there any way to make an alias for `function` keyword, something like `fn` or `func`? `fn sayHello () {}`

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly No, there's not, though of course you can design your own programming language and compile that to JavaScript. Look at https://www.sweetjs.org or http://coffeescript.org/